# if else actions / array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have google voice recognition in my application.

Now i'm trying to start actions by voice.
Here is the code in my onActivityResult

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            // add commands


        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

So i'll be getting the keywords from the array 'matches'. So should the array for 'matches' be like this?

```
String[] matches = {"rotate","rotate clockwise"};
```

'matches' on both lines of code, are grayed out and is said that they are never used.

Then back to the onActivityResult. How should i make the code for the actions. Something like this?

```
  if ("closer".equalsIgnoreCase(command.getText().toString())) {
 PUT CODE HERE
}
```

but that code is for a editText, how can i modify it to work with google voice.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. Please, reformulate your question.

Comment: I have google voice recognition in my app.  Now i want to be able to say a word, and some code will run.      Here is an example.  If i have a edit text and i want to be able to type in a word and some code will run.  Here is some code that does it: http://i.imgur.com/tZNcjDr.png ..... But instead of typing in a word,  i am saying a word.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your received array and check if there is a matching value.

eg:

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

   ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

    if(isStringMatch("closer", matches)){
      // String match => execute your code
    }

}
```

And this is the `isStringMatch()` method:

```
private boolean isStringMatch(String str, ArrayList<String> list){

  for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
     if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(i))){
        return true;
     }
  }

  return false;
}
```